# Alternate row color

Tags: css, css-tables

I want to display alternate rows in different color. I have specified the color in CSS. And most of the rows are working properly.When I checked, rows are having either class="odd" or class="even" but some rows are having class="odd even" and class="even odd". How it is happening ? Could anyone explain why it is taking the class as "odd even" or "even odd". Thanks in advance.

```
table.dataTable .odd { background-color:  red; }
table.dataTable .even { background-color: green;  }
```

Comment: Could you post some code, please?

Comment: Are you using pagination?

Comment: you have a try code please post your code

Comment: "How it is happening ?" Who knows.... We don't have your code in front of us...

Comment: I have attached my code

Comment: No, you've attached your CSS, that isn't code. How are you adding the classes to the `<tr>` tags?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are you even using classes for this?

```
tr {background-color:white}
tr:nth-child(even) {background-color:black}
```

Comment: This would be the best solution, it seems a bit of a waste to use `modulus` just to add the class to alternating rows.

Comment: Maybe they want to support <IE8?

Comment: Possibly, seems odd though that you would use a different solution (server side modulus) just to support 1 or 2 old browser versions.

Comment: @anothershrubery If they can't be bothered to update their browsers, I can't be bothered to waste time coding specifically for them. Ni!

Answer (score 0):

try css

```
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function()
    {
      $("tr:even").css("background-color", "#000000");
    });
```

OR

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to support the older browsers (like IE8), nth-child doesnt work. A simple workarround would be a combination of Kolink's and falguni's solution:

```
tr {background-color:white}
tr:nth-child(even), tr.even {background-color:black}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("tr:even").addClass('even');
});
```

The solution falguni gave has a bad practice, it uses JS to update styles. If you decide it should not be black, but blue you would have to change two locations. My example does not need that.

My code can be improved, you could check if the user supports the :nth-selector, and IF NOT (add class) for performance.